# How to discover Implicit multiple root

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteriaquery

here's my show case code:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> q = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<AA> aa = q.from(AA.class);

q.multiselect(aa.get("id").alias("id"),
articolo.get("a").alias("a"),
articolo.get("b").alias("b"),
articolo.get("c").get("t").alias("c"),
articolo.get("d").alias("d"));

System.out.println("RootCount: "+q.getRoots().size());

Query query = em.createQuery(q);
List<Tuple> list = query.getResultList();
```

Where AA is a mapped Table and c is a CC type item (in wich CC is another mapped table):

well, i'm not allowed to insert an image, so: [Tables Schema](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/3383/catturass.png)

c is a foreignkey referencing the table CC

So, the above code will print "RootCount: 1" (only one root) but the resulting query would be something like this:

```
select aa.id, aa.a, aa.b, cc.t, aa.d from AA aa, CC cc where aa.c=cc.id
```

so...two roots, but the q.getRoots() report only the one i explicitly have defined.

How can i get the real roots?

Comment: Added JPA tags, this is not the Hibernate Criteria API, but the JPA 2 Criteria API (even if hibernate is the provider)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do only have one root. That said, there is nothing stopping you from declaring multiple roots, and manually joining them.

```
Root<AA> aa = query.from(AA.class)
Path<CC> aaToCc = aa.get("c");
Root<CC> cc = query.from(CC.class)

cb.where(cb.equal(aaToCcId, cc));
```

The trick is, you don't really need the CC root. You can just use teh `Path<CC>` pretty much like a root. Alternatively, you can use `aa.join`.

Comment: yes, the query just work also without the CC root but when i use getRoots() ther's no sign of CC while it's used.

Comment: What if the connection between two tables is not using foreign keys? What if the connection is using some string field? What if while fetching data from `CC`, we want to check certain condition with the field in `CC` and also that it is not used in `AA`? How can this be achieved?